# Can I have ssh without scp also?

Tags: ssh, scp

A project I'm on requires I upload some files to a vendor's remote server.  I requested a secure connection, and suggested scp or https or sftp.  In response, they stated they could grant me ssh access, but they didn't support scp.

I know you can have scp access without ssh access (via, say, http://sublimation.org/scponly/ ), but hadn't heard of ssh without scp before.

Aside from the question of why have the setup this way, is this possible?  ssh without scp?

Comment: How come they "don't support" it? It's pretty much a zero-conf solution.

Comment: I wonder if they really *know* if they support it. Maybe they just know about the SSH part, and don't know they actually support file transfers as well? Just try...?

Comment: Yeah, I plan on just trying it to see.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently, [it is possible](http://fixunix.com/unix/380560-how-restrict-ssh-users-block-scp-sftp.html) (according to post #3 at that link).  The trick is in the [authorized_keys](http://man.he.net/man5/authorized_keys) file format.  There are several options that allow the server to restrict SSH features based on what key was used to authenticate.  The "command=" option allows the server administrator to attach a restriction on the public key -- something like

> "any incoming connections that authenticate with this key will execute this command, regardless of what command might have been requested by the user".

It might prevent the execution of standard SCP and SFTP, but if it provides an interactive shell there's probably a way around it:

```
$ ssh user@host 'cat /some/where/whatiwant.txt' > igotit.txt
```

Comment: This also shows that what the client does has nothing to do with security (besides a false idea thereof). Once you have a shell you can do what you want. The feature is to limit to other commands

Comment: Yeah, if you are trying to transfer non-media files over slow connections I use $ ssh remote.box.com "cat /dir/file | gzip" | gunzip > dir/file"

Comment: Tar is a better choice than `cat` or `gzip/gunzip` for piping files through an ssh connection. It will transfer whole directory trees and preserve file permissions & timestamps. [See here.](http://serverfault.com/questions/39027/easiest-way-for-fast-transfer-of-files-between-linux-servers/39111#39111)

Comment: fixunix.com <-- dead link

Answer (score 2):

There is also [FISH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Files_transferred_over_shell_protocol) to get around precisely this irritating situation.

Answer (score 1):

Although it's possible to disable scp and sftp and have only SSH access, typical setups with [SSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell#Uses_of_SSH) access have [scp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_copy#SCP_protocol) and [sftp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_file_transfer_protocol) access enabled since they all use the same family of protocols.

I use [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php) to copy files to my server with an SSH setup all the time.